# Listen for changes in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Spreadsheet as database for some simple applications.

Today I have a php script wich updates the application, when a update button is pressed manually.

I figure there might be another way to automaticly update my application when changes in the Google Spreadsheet are made. Best would be if the application could be updated 10 minutes after last change in the  Google Sheet document.

Any ideá how to solve that?

Comment: Is using Appscript's [onEdit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) to make an request to your app for an update, a viable option?